# package myproject/pkg/api is not in std (/usr/local/go/src/myproject/pkg/api)

Tags: go

I am creating my first project in golang. I am having trouble familiarizing with the concept of URL as package so I decided to make everything local.

My project structure is like this:

```
myproject
├── cmd
│   └── myapp
│       └── main.go
├── go.mod
├── pkg
│   └── api
│       └── serve.go
└── README.md
```

I tried to be inspired by this: https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout/tree/master/cmd

I generated the `go.mod` using

```
cd ~/myproject
go mod init myproject/cmd/myapp
```

In my `main.go` I have:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "myproject/pkg/api"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")
}
```

I run myapp using `go run cmd/myapp/main.go`

However I get:

```
cmd/myapp/main.go:5:5: package myproject/pkg/api is not in std (/usr/local/go/src/myproject/pkg/api)
```

Comment: Run the package, not the file. `go run ./cmd/myapp`

Comment: same error ... @BurakSerdar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go mod init myproject/cmd/myapp` is incorrect, or at least, likely not what you intended. Whatever the module name is becomes the import root of your module, which means to import `cmd/myapp` you'd have to use `myproject/cmd/myapp/cmd/myapp`.

You most likely want `go mod init myproject` instead. You can also correct this manually by editing the `module` line in your `go.mod`.

Take a look at the `go.mod` file in the example project you referenced: https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout/blob/master/go.mod

```
module github.com/YOUR-USER-OR-ORG-NAME/YOUR-REPO-NAME
```

Also see:

- [How to Write Go Code](https://go.dev/doc/code)
- [Go Tutorial: How to Create a Module](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/create-module)